# Why can I not execute my java project from a script?

Tags: java, jar, cygwin, sh, executable-jar

I am working on a project that has many *module* jar files, one of which conains my main class; I am trying to write a shell script that will setup the class path and then start the application; here is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
java -cp "modules/*;lib/*" com.example.Launcher
```

In this example, `com.example.Launcher` is the class that contains *public static void main(String[] args)...*

The issue that I am facing is that when executing my script by `./myscript` I am give the output

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Launcher

This would be simple, there is something wrong with the classpath right?

But if directly from the command line I execute

```
java -cp "modules/*;lib/*" com.example.Launcher
```

the exact same command from the script, in the directory the script resides, everything works just fine.

Any thoughts?

*side note*
I am running this via CygWin

*another side note*
This might be an issue with *sh* in CygWin. I coppied this build to a CentOS machine and tried executing it, changing the `;` to a `:` allowed for execution from the script.

The issue persists on my window machine even with the change.

*a third sidenote*
It would again appear that the issue is with *sh* in CygWin, my final solution was this:

launcher.sh will invoke java using a `:` in the classpath

launcher.bat will invoke java using a `;` in the classpath

Comment: Not sure why the execution on the command line works, but try to use ':' as path separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix-like systems the seperator is a `:` (not a `;`). Change

```
java -cp "modules/*;lib/*" com.example.Launcher
```

to

```
java -cp "modules/*:lib/*" com.example.Launcher
```

Comment: I am thinking the issue is with _sh_ on CygWin. I tried running the build on a CentOS machine with this change, and it worked fine executing it from the script, still no avail on my windows machine though :/

Comment: If you're on Windows, use a powershell, bat or cmd script. Cygwin invokes through the posix compatibility layer (which *might* be an issue).

Comment: Hmmmm, so the issue i think is with running it via _sh_ in CygWin, I now have a _.sh_ that will use `:` in the classpath, and a _.bat_ that will use `;`, all now seems well and good; cheers.